# access a specific property of domain class in my controller

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

Hi I have a program where there are two domain classes. One that has different properties of my data objects (e.g. People) and another which is a User domain class which checks the login id and password to see if the user is authorized to make changes to the database. In my "People" domain class I have a property field called "createdID". I want to set the login id of person who created a new entry in the database to this field. I have been able to get the login id of the person from my user controller class to my people controller class but how do I set the createdID field of my people domain class to this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def peopleInstance = new People()   
peopleInstance.createdId = <whatever value you want to set>
peopleInstance.save()
```

Comment: That almost worked for me but I had to add one more tag in that. It worked for me when i did peopleInstance.properties.createdID=...